# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: heroku, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I'm trying to make the login in heroku but I get this:

```
$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: xxx@gmail.com
Password (typing will be hidden):
 ▸    Post https://api.heroku.com/login: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I already try to generate a ssl certificate but it cannot solve the problem. I don't know if it is problem or not of the ssl.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: What user agent are you using?

Comment: Also, what ruby version are you using?

Comment: And what version of heroku toolbelt?

Comment: Are you behind a company proxy or firewall?

Comment: @ivarni no. I'm not behind.

Comment: what's your OS and version?

Comment: Windows 10 , and i'm trying to do this in bash on Ubuntu on Windows. @Allen

Comment: can you `cat /etc/lsb-release` from your ubuntu?

Comment: @Allen Sure.

`DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"`

Comment: changing from the `heroku-toolbelt` package installed via brew to the latest OS X `.pkg` from Heroku's page solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running this command worked for me:

`HEROKU_SSL_VERIFY=disable heroku login`

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same error and a simple **update of heroku-cli** on my machine fixed it! I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.2 and originally installed heroku with [homebrew](http://brew.sh)... But this command should work with any operating system, assuming that you're using heroku-cli (heroku *command line interface*)

So first just run:

`$ heroku update`

You should get the output:

`heroku-cli: Updating plugins... done`

`heroku-cli: Updating... done.`

Then try and login again:

`$ heroku login`

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Cannot update heroku. Receiving this error; Get https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/manifest.json: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Answer (score 2):

This command will tell you more, type in the terminal:

`curl -I https://api.heroku.com/login -vvv`

One possible reason is DNS poison.

Comment: I receive this:
`"* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying **.***.***.***...
* Connected to api.heroku.com (**.***.***.***) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"`

Answer (score 1):

**unable to get local issuer certificate** shows you missing the CA, api.heroku.com was signed by DigiCert_High_Assurance_EV_Root_CA.crt, please refer to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu) to check your CA, especially that `mozilla/DigiCert_High_Assurance_EV_Root_CA.crt` is **NOT** disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue with following steps:

- `mv ~/.netrc ~/.netrc.backup`

  - or you can remove `~/.netrc` completely
- `heroku login`